# What's the best way to migrate from a Windows NT domain to Windows 2000/2003 domain?

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-server-2008, active-directory, windows-server-2000

I have an old Windows NT domain in need to upgrade to Windows 2000/2003 Active Directory.  There is one PDC and two BDCs.  What should my next steps be?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

My approach would be:

1. Make sure the PDC and BDCs are in sync
2. Switch off the BDCs and disconnect them
3. Upgrade the PDC to Windows 2000, giving the domain a FQDN (ie from FOO to foo.bar.local)
4. Make sure that the domain members, ie other servers and desktops have converted properly
5. Wipe the BDCs, install windows 2000/2003/2008 from scratch, add to the domain and then promote to DC
6. Tranfer the FSMO roles away from the ex-PDC
7. Demote the ex-PDC
8. Take the ex-PDC out of the domain, rebuild it from scratch as Windows 2000/3/8
9. Promote the ex-PDC back to being a DC
10. Move the FSMO roles around until you're happy.

Note that if you're planning on doing a hardware upgrade at the same time, then there would be a few differences.

If anything goes wrong before step 5, you can bring up a BDC, promote to PDC and keep using your NT4 domain until you've fixed the problem.

Comment: Don't think there is anything much else to add to this answer hence it being the only one!

Comment: If someone wrote up a "how to" for the case where the AD DCs are going on new hardware from the old NT4 PDC/BDC then that would be worth marking up.